# How to create specific time buckets from time column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which has a column `time` with these unique values

```
0      15:54:16
1      16:25:24
2      16:54:40
3      17:27:16
4      18:23:30
5      18:48:38
6      10:24:45
7      11:25:41
8      12:26:42
9      13:29:11
10     14:32:45
11     15:32:00
12     16:30:19
13     17:33:04
14     18:31:15
         ...   
450    06:18:34
451    18:47:22
452    07:43:53
453    08:37:06
454    09:27:41
455    13:26:42
456    10:57:58
457    11:59:33
458    12:58:45
459    14:28:37
460    16:28:10
461    07:58:07
462    19:59:23
463    20:31:53
464    09:58:47
```

I want to transform this column to time buckets. I would like the buckets to be specific: `0to6, 6to10, 10to14, 14to16, 16to19 and 19to0`

Is there a way to do this without using the `numpy.where` ?

Comment: are those buckets hours? so 00:00:00 to 06:00:00?

Comment: @ALollz yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `pd.cut`:

```
df[1] = pd.to_timedelta(df[1])

bins = pd.to_timedelta([0,6,10,14,16,19,24], unit='H')
pd.cut(df[1], bins=bins, include_lowest=True)
```

Output:

```
0     (0 days 14:00:00, 0 days 16:00:00]
1     (0 days 16:00:00, 0 days 19:00:00]
2     (0 days 16:00:00, 0 days 19:00:00]
3     (0 days 16:00:00, 0 days 19:00:00]
4     (0 days 16:00:00, 0 days 19:00:00]
5     (0 days 16:00:00, 0 days 19:00:00]
6     (0 days 10:00:00, 0 days 14:00:00]
7     (0 days 10:00:00, 0 days 14:00:00]
8     (0 days 10:00:00, 0 days 14:00:00]
9     (0 days 10:00:00, 0 days 14:00:00]
10    (0 days 14:00:00, 0 days 16:00:00]
11    (0 days 14:00:00, 0 days 16:00:00]
12    (0 days 16:00:00, 0 days 19:00:00]
13    (0 days 16:00:00, 0 days 19:00:00]
14    (0 days 16:00:00, 0 days 19:00:00]
```